# Using .htaccess to create clean URL structure

Tags: .htaccess

How do i redirect

website.com/path/?p=4927304

to

website.com/path/4927304

where the number is dynamic.

Many thanks

Comment: @the_drow
Has been answered before (shows up in related links)

Comment: @Robus: If you downvoted, please leave a comment. Especially if it's a dup so other people can vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

This rule will redirect URLs like `/path/?p=4927304` to `/path/4927304`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^path/$ /path/%1 [R]
```

Comment: I believe it should be RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)$