# How do I remove a variable name from a URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So basically I want users to be able to go to my website with a URL of something like `/45678`, instead of having to use `/?p=45678`, so really I just want to remove the variable name. I've tried using mod_rewrite, but it seems that is only for removing the name when the page is visited.

Here is the current code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+=$

RewriteRule ^/$ /%1 [R]
```

Comment: Mod_rewrite is exactly what you need for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179241/using-htaccess-to-create-clean-url-structure

Comment: Then you've probably written your rewrite rule wrong, edit your post and include the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change all of your links to /45678 rather than ?p=45678. Or did I misunderstand you completely? Because what I got from your post is that it works properly, unless you manually access the ?p=45678 where as it stays as ?p=45678.

**EDIT:**
This is what I am using for http://www.madphp.org/dev/, give it a go, works like a charm for me (it also removes the index.php part). To access your now cleaner URL you would simply explode the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable to get all of the required parameters within your PHP script.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, basically I want to use the .htaccess file to take the /45678 part of the URL and make it a PHP GET variable so that the URL looks clean

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but it still isn't working, my page is just telling me that the variable is undefined, so I would imagine that this isn't passing it the /45678 as ?p=, and the plus side the site isn't returning a 404 error.

Comment: Change it to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?p=$1 [L]

Comment: Oh crap, I forgot to mention that my .htaccess works with the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable, my bad. Do as CaseySoftware suggested and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up mod_rewrite correctly? If so, you can use variables like simple `$_GET` variables, in this case you must access `$_GET['p']` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I did this without using .htaccess, but it does query a database. I wrote this a while ago so it uses PEAR DB, adjust to your database/connection method. I'll just copy my code and let you figure out what changes you need.

```
$db=connect_db();
$name=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 20);
$name=strtolower($name);
$id=$db->getone("select id from user where login='{$name}'");
header("Location: /dragonart/profile?user=" . $id);
```

If you store your information in a database this may be a nice alternative. The downside is that the the URL is not rewritten and the user is ultimately sent to a page with ending in a $_GET variable.

edit:
Just realized that using my method a simpler method can be used for the answer. Since my solution was used to find the id of a user using their username and then send someone to their profile (which requires the id) a better solution would be something like:

```
$var=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $length);  
header("Location: /path/to/page?p=".$var);
```

where $length is the usual length of the URL without the variable at the end.